# reset the amount of a variable in c

Tags: c

Hello i'm trying to write a program that can evaluate if a number is in Fibonacci series:

> (1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 ..... )

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main() {
    int received,n1,n2,n3,i;
    do {
        printf("Please enter a number to evaluate : ");
        n1=1;
        n2=1;
        i=0;    
        scanf("%d",&received);
        while(n3<received) {
            if (i==1) { 
                n1=1;
            }
            else {
                n3=n1+n2;
                n1=n2;
                n2=n3;
            }
            i++;
            printf("%4d \n",n1);
        }
        if(n1==received || n2==received || n3==received) {
            printf("True ! The number is in Fibonacci series \n");
        }
        else {
            printf("False ! The number is not in Fibonacci series \n");
        }
    }while(received>0);

    printf("Error occured !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    getch();    
}
```

But when I want to reset the amount of the variables it does not work:

```
n1=1;
n2=1;
i=0;
```

Comment: `it does not work` => what do you mean?

Comment: You are using `n3` uninitialized in `while(n3<received)`, this is undefined behaviour

Comment: reset the amount of variables in lines 9,10,11 . i can see that variables have their pervious amount.

Comment: @ARASH Put that info in the question not in comments. "It doesn't work" by itself is not useful.

Comment: @Keine Lust thank you so much i did not attach n3 any amount it works very well thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Variable `n3` is uninitialized.  The test `while (i < received)` invokes undefined behavior the first time, how the program behaves after that is not important.

You can correct and simplify the code by making `n3` the current Fibonacci number, starting at `1`, and stepping through subsequent numbers with you formula.  An initial value of `0` for `n1` and `n2` gives the correct sequence.

Also note that you should check the return value of `scanf` and you should exit the loop when the use enters `0`.

Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) {
    int received, n1, n2, n3;
    for (;;) {
        printf("Please enter a number to evaluate : ");
        if (scanf("%d", &received) != 1)
            break;
        if (received <= 0)
            break;
        n1 = 0;
        n2 = 0;
        n3 = 1;    
        while (n3 < received) {
            n1 = n2;
            n2 = n3;
            n3 = n1 + n2;
            printf("%4d\n", n3);
        }
        if (n3 == received) {
            printf("True! The number is in Fibonacci series\n");
        } else {
            printf("False! The number is not in Fibonacci series\n");
        }
    }
    getch();    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you meant the i

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
int received,n1,n2,n3,i;
do
{
printf("Please enter a number to evaluate : ");
n1=1;
n2=1;
i=0;    
scanf("%d",&received);
 while(i<received)
 {
    if (i==1)
 {   
     n1=1;
  }else
 {
 n3=n1+n2;
 n1=n2;
 n2=n3;
 }
 i++;
 printf("%4d \n",n1) ;
 }
 if(n1==received || n2==received || n3==received)
 {
    printf("True ! The number is in Fibonacci series \n");
 }else
 {
    printf("False ! The number is not in Fibonacci series \n");
 }   
 }while(received>0);
printf("Error occured !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
getch();    
 }*
```

if not then u need to initialize n3

Comment: Make sure your code is correctly edited and give a bit more explanations :)

Comment: You still invoke undefined behavior if the user enters `0` the first time as `n3` is uninitialized in the `if(n1==received || n2==received || n3==received)` test.  `n3` must be initialized in all cases.